# SharePoint list item events are not fired if item has lot of data

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

I have a SharePoint provider hosted app to process list item events (Item Create/Update/Updating). Server side solution is hosted in Azure and it just writes a small entry to database when event is received. This is working fine and on item create/update we get the entry in database.

However, if we put say around 40,000 characters in a multi-line text column of the item, then we are not receving the event. Item is saved successfully. After this if we update the item by only changing the title then also event is not received. After that we create a new item with less data then event is received for the new item.

Please let me know if there are any limitations around this or is there something I can do in my provider hosted app or SharePoint to get the event in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a reference of below answered thread:

- Remote Event Receiver does not fire

[image]

On another hand, Remote event receivers run immediately, but because they run on a remote server, you might encounter a communication failure. Per the [docs suggestions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint), it 's a better solution to use the remote event receiver pattern with a change log pattern, which will provide a more reliable architecture.

- [Query SharePoint change log with ChangeQuery and ChangeToken](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/query-sharepoint-change-log-with-changequery-and-changetoken)

BR